# How to connect to new Datasource in an Access 2016 VB Application?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

My department uses an application created using VB and Access 2016. It originally pointed to a database on one of our servers. After migrating the data to a different server, I now need it pointing to the other database on that different server. But I can't seem to make the connection.

I have 'dbowner' permissions on the server in question.

The original code for connection string was as follows:

```
'Remove the filter, close the log on form, and open the Switchboard
rst.Filter = 0
DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmUserLogOn"

'Open the Main Switchboard
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmMain", acNormal

'Open the InactiveShutDown form in Hidden mode
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmInactiveShutDown", acNormal, , , , acHidden
.
.
.
Set conn = CurrentProject.Connection
.
.
.
rstLog.Open "tblUserLog", conn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
rstLog.AddNew
rstLog!UserID = rst!UserID
rstLog!TimeIn = Now()
rstLog.Update
```

**My new code is as follows:**

```
'DoCmd.OpenForm "frmInactiveShutDown", acNormal, , , , acHidden
'Commented out the above statement
.
.
.    
'Set conn = CurrentProject.Connection
    '==================================================================
    'Start of Added Code for SQL Migration
    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    With conn
    .ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLNCLI11;Data Source=(My Server Name);Initial Catalog=(My Database Name);User ID=(Username);Password=(Password)"
    .Open
    If .State = adStateClosed Then
    MsgBox "Connection unsuccessful. Could not open connection.", vbInformation, "Error:"
    End If
    End With

    Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset

    With rst
    .ActiveConnection = conn
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .CursorType = adOpenStatic
    .LockType = adLockOptimistic
    .Open "tbl_Users"
    End With
    'End of Added Code for SQL Migration - See Section 2 for rest of code.
    '==================================================================
.
.
.
.
.
        'Section 2 of Code
                '==================================================================
                'Start of added code for SQL Migration
                rstLog.Open "tblUserLog", conn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
                rstLog.AddNew
                rstLog!UserID = rst!UserID
                rstLog!TimeIn = DateTime.Now()
                rstLog.Update
                MsgBox "Success! Connection was made successfully.", vbInformation
                'End of added code for SQL Migration
                '===================================================================
```

My form has a drop down to select list of users form a table. I added a test user in that table but that test user doesn't show up in the drop down list. Hence, I think the connection is not being made.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: *using VB and Access 2016*... Is this really VB or VBA? Two different language types. Please match language in text with tags.

Comment: Set a breakpoint and set through it. You don't have any error trapping so I think it's connecting because it's not crashing on you?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms807027.aspx - I like example 5